# To c-bet or not to c-bet against bigstack?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, hand

I'm considering a hand I played in play money. I had JQo vs 33 and I don't remember exactly what position I was in but it was relatively late position. It looked like this:

I had 3k chips (play money) and my opponent had 8k so I was the short stack and he was the big stack. Preflop, I raised 3bb to 160 in late position and he called in one of the blinds.

The flop was 2T3. He had a set (333, 12% chance obviously). I had nothing but I c-bet the size of the pot (between 300 and 400, I don't remember). He check/called my big raise. I should have thought "wait a moment, he could have folded if he had nothing but he check/called so he probably has something"--he had some nice hand but I didn't determine his range.

But a Q came on the turn and it forced me to bet another pot-size bet and he re-raised (so he's telling me he has a set by doing this). I called :|

This was the story. My question is: what should I have done?

I think c-betting in general is proper because it's a dry board with one opponent.

But what about in this case where there is a bigstack?

Comment: Need to clean up the question.   So he re-raised, told you he had a set, and you called?

Comment: yes but he don't told me literally that he had set so I would fold re-raise? but i was involved into pot

Comment: How did the Q on the turn force you to raise, and if he "told you" he had a set, why did you call when you were drawing dead?

Comment: Forgive me if English is not your first language, but this hand history is very difficult to follow. If you cannot remember position, action or pot sizes (as you mention a couple of times), you probably weren't paying enough attention to the hand anyway.

Comment: yes English is not my native language and there are two sides: first if I folded I wouldn't know that he had a set, second thus I called I know that it was a bad move so I gained exp and bonus side it is play money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you both were quite deep in this situation therefore you were a big stack too despite your stack was smaller than a villain's.

Let's analyse situation.
Pre-flop: You raised with JQo in LP (late position) and he called out of position either in SB or BB. You don't remember which position he called but it is quite important as SB in general will call with a much stronger holding than BB.
Flop: 2T3. You didn't mention suits of cards as a flush draw will make a difference in this hand. Let say the board came all in different suits. In that case, it was pretty safe board for you to c-bet. So any bet around 50%-60% would almost always win it instantly. Your pot sized bet didn't make sense as it actually looked like you were bluffing and wanted just to win this pot. I would straightaway re-raise you on the flop with nothing on this flop. Now even if there was a flash draw, your 50% bet will win it again most of the time. Problem is this board can logically mostly hit SB/BB range rather than yours.
Turn: Q comes and he checks again. Now you got a pair but you want to keep pot small. You should check back to extract some value/bluff catching on the river + to call a river bet will be much cheaper for you. Instead you bet pot size again. Very bad bet which will only get called and raised by better hands. You get re-raised on turn by a player who plays out of position. That is usually a very strong hand. You should instantly fold to that re-raise: you cannot beat anything other than bluff. If you call him you get pot committed and almost all in under any circumstances.

Comment: this was dry board and rainbow flop if it was wet i could semibluff and in addition he played bad he had to protect his set

Comment: @Grisza Had to protect his set?  He checked the flop and turn - that is the opposite of protect.  He did not play bad.  He got you to put in all you chips with top pair.

Comment: he would i meant

Answer (score 0):

A c bet is appropriate like 90% of the time.  10% don't do it (with both made and un-made hands) just so they cannot count on a c bet.

If you hit nothing and no draw and flop that could have hit the villain then just check fold.

Neither of you are short stacked so c bet should not be effected.  In a tournament you need to be aware you getting into a pot that could take you out but you are in the pot.

A full pot bet is a bit expensive.  1/2 pot has nearly the same effect at a lower cost.

On the turn a 1/2 pot bet would also have nearly the same effect.  If you bet 1/2 on the flop you should bet 1/2 on the turn - don't announce the Q hit you.

A raise on the turn means a made hand or a bluff.  Any value bet likely has you beat. He is probably not raising with a TT.  If 2 or 3 hit then you have to suspect a set as a lone 2 or 3 is not likely to call a pre flop raise.

Say the re-raise was the size of the pot and you are getting 2:1.  He would need to be bluffing 1/3 of the time to make that call.  I don't see that as a bluff 1/3 the time.   It is not like there was a strong draw to get you off of.  In a tournament you cannot call and you should try and keep pot size down (especially against a bigger stack).

Villain had a hand that was likely best and would likely hold up.  I am surprised he did not call the turn and then raise the river.

Comment: he slowplayed a bit thx for feedback

Comment: Villain played very well versus this guy who played very poorly. You check raise the turn and make a big bet on river - that is the way to make some money. You cannot check call all streets - an aggressor will just check the river in position and you will lose a lot of money

Comment: @KananFarzali I didn't check raised, the Villain did this